# Difficulty understanding the method of undetermined coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the particular solution for this equation:

$$y'' - 4y' + y = t*e^t + t$$

My initial thought was to use linearity and find the particular solution for both $t*e^t$ and $t$ and then just add them together. So I chose to start with $t*e^t$ and "guessed" the solution to be $t*e^t$ like this

$$y_1 = t*e^t\\y_1' = e^t + t*e^t\\y_1'' = 2*e^t + t*e^t$$

after substituting this back into the original equation and simplifying I get:
$$-2 - 2*t = t$$

and this is where I'm stuck. Right now this method seems completely random, and you're always dependent on seeing the "bigger picture" by already knowing what other terms you're looking for. Please explain how to proceed with this issue, and explain how you're thinking as well.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $1$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial $x^2-4x+1=0$, the trial solution with undetermined coefficients is
$$
y_{p_1}=(A+Bt)·e^t.
$$
And as $0$ is equally not a root of the characteristic polynomial, the trial solution for the second part is
$$
y_{p_2}=C+Dt
$$

---

In general, for a right side term $p(t)·e^{\lambda t}$, and with $λ$ having multiplicity $m$ as root of the characteristic polynomial ($m=0$ if not a root), the trial solution is
$$
y_p=t^m·q(t)·e^{λt},
$$
with $\deg q=\deg p$ and the coefficients of $q$ are the undetermined coefficinents